# How to close jQuery Dialog within the dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How to close jQuery Dialog within the dialog without using the close button?

Inside the Dialog is a simple form request. If a successful submission occurs, then the UI dialog automatically closes and refreshes the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 200,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="form-dialog" title="Form Submit">
    <form action="default.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" value=" " />    
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />

        <a href="#" id="btnDone">CLOSE</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnDone").click(function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            });
        });
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 73):

you can close it programmatically by calling

```
$('#form-dialog').dialog('close')
```

whenever you want.

Comment: But the form tag is inside the ui dialog. No jquery files inside the ui dialog, just a plain form tag submission.

How can I use the $('#form-dialog').close() inside the #form-dialog? It's like closing itself after you click something or a waiting timer occurs inside the ui dialog.

Comment: if you are using jquery to open the dialog, you can use jquery to close it. in the line right under where you declare the dialog, set `$('#mySubmitButton').live('click', function() { mySubmitFunction(); $('#form-dialog').close(); });`

Comment: Yes, but how about when I'm inside the dialog? I think the equivalent of this is something like $(window).unload() where the pop-up form automatically closes itself rather than clicking the jquery-ui-dialog close button.

Comment: dude. how do you know when the user is done w/your form? at whatever point that is, invoke `$('#form-dialog').close()`

Comment: I have this similar issue but I don't think it's been marked as answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644365/closing-a-jquery-modal-dialog-from-a-remote-page

Comment: this will not work....you need $('selector').dialog('close') just .close will not work

Comment: err... yeah, what @redsquare said

Answer (score 70):

Try This

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

It will close the dialog inside it.

Comment: Is good when you have dynamic html instead of a reference to an element

Answer (score 19):

You need

```
$('selector').dialog('close');
```

Comment: Hi redsquare, I've added a few lines on my code above, may I know why it won't close the dialog? As you can see, the close button is inside the ui-dialog. Thanks.

Comment: because in your case this refers to the button not the dialog

Comment: change $(this) to $("#form-dialog")

Answer (score 14):

Close from iframe inside a dialog:

```
window.parent.$('.ui-dialog-content:visible').dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('close')
```

Simple, I like to make sure I don't:

1. hardcode dialog #id values.
2. Close all dialogs.

Answer (score 5):

After checking all of these answers above without luck, the folling code worked for me to solve the problem:

```
$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");
```

Maybe this will be also a good try if you seek for alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

replace one  string to

```
$("#form-dialog").dialog('close');
```

$(this) here means another object $("#btnDone")

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 200,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="form-dialog" title="Form Submit">
<form action="default.aspx" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value=" " />    
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

<a href="#" id="btnDone">CLOSE</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnDone").click(function () {
 //I've replaced next string
 // $(this) here means another object $("#btnDone")
  $("#form-dialog").dialog('close');
    });
});
</script>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `$(this).dialog('close');` only works inside the click function of a button within the modal. If your button is not within the dialog box, as in this example, specify a selector:

```
$('#form-dialog').dialog('close');
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Answer (score 1):

better way is "destroy and remove" instead of "close" 
it will remove dialog's "html" from the DOM

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form-dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 200,
                draggable: true,
                resizable: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $("#idDialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

This will make you a button to close. you can also call the function close

```
$("#idDialog").dialog("close");
```

in some function to do this. or even in a button/a

```
< a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnDone"   
                              onClick="$("#idDialog").dialog("close");">CLOSE</a>
```

**EDIT:**
you need this to include your dialog into form:

```
open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this link in the open

```
$(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [jconfirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) the way of closing it programatically is the following:

```
jconfirm.instances[0].close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#IDOFDialog").hide()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.