# jquery close dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I wanna close a jquery modal dialog with a button that is within a form inside the modal...

```
$("#btnCancel").button().on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#modalDlgWindow").dialog("close");
});

function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $loading = $('<img src="../../Content/assets/images/nivo-loader.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
    var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
    var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
    $("#modalDlgWindow").empty();
    $("#modalDlgWindow")
        .append($loading)
        .load($url)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false
            , resizable: false
            , autoResize: true
            , title: $title
            , width: 'auto'
            , modal: false
            , height: 'auto'
            , show: 'fade'
            , position: [10, 50]
            , hide: 'fade'
        });
    $("#modalDlgWindow").dialog('open');
};
```

It works with `.fadeOut(500)` and `.empty()` and so I thought that it would also work with `.dialog('close')` but it doesn't. Does anyone have a solution to my problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [How to close jQuery Dialog within the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933826/how-to-close-jquery-dialog-within-the-dialog)

Try:

```
 $("#modalDlgWindow").closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

Alternatively, you could add a cancel (and a submit) button like so:

```
function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $loading = $('<img src="../../Content/assets/images/nivo-loader.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
    var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
    var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
    $("#modalDlgWindow").empty();
    $("#modalDlgWindow")
        .append($loading)
        .load($url)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false
            , resizable: false
            , autoResize: true
            , title: $title
            , width: 'auto'
            , modal: false
            , height: 'auto'
            , show: 'fade'
            , position: [10, 50]
            , hide: 'fade'
        });

        $("#modalDlgWindow").dialog("option", "buttons", {
                "Submit": function () {
                       // Get form values here

                       $.ajax({
                              type: 'POST',
                              //post form information here,
                              success: function (msg) {
                              if (msg.d) {
                                 $(this).dialog("close");                                    
                                }
                              },
                              error: function () {
                                 alert("Error! Try again...");
                              }
                       });
                    },
              "Cancel": function () {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
               }
            );
    $("#modalDlgWindow").dialog('open');
};
```

Comment: i've tried this but it didn't work i also tried 
    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('close')
and still it didn't work...

Comment: Edited - try with `$("#modalDlgWindow")`.

Comment: still not working... is it because within the dialog i have a partial view? I've tried to do alert($("#modalDlgWindow")) to see if the object existed, the problem could be from there, but i got [object OBJECT], so from what i can conclude it exists and should be possible to close it, is there any other way? Thanks in advance and for the tip.

Comment: See edit - you could a different approach, adding the close button to the dialog.