# how to close a JQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got the following dialog which loads displayRecords.php. I've got the close button on the dialog but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

     var dlg=$('#ticketDetails').dialog({
        title: 'Ticket Details',
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen:false,
        modal: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
        close: function(e, i) { $(this).hide(); },
        width: 1300


     });


    $('a.view').click(

    function(e) 
    {    

         dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){ 
         dlg.dialog('open');

     });

    });

});
```

I'm rather new to JQuery. Can someone please point out what looks wrong in the above?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933826/how-to-close-jquery-dialog-within-the-dialog suggests `dlg.dialog('close');`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: yup thats what I'm using but i can't seem to figure out why its failing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dlg = '';
$(document).ready(function() { 

     dlg=$('#ticketDetails').dialog({
        title: 'Ticket Details',
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen:false,
        modal: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
        close: function(e, i) { $(this).hide(); },
        width: 1300   
     });


    $('a.view').click(

    function(e) 
    {    

         dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){ 
         dlg.dialog('open');

     });

    });


 $('a.closeDialog').click(function(){dlg.dialog('close');});
});
```

A couple minor adjustments, that may work in concept. The idea I am giving is declaring `dlg` outside of the function as a global variable of sorts, that the remaining functions can reuse

Comment: its defined in your DOM... hopefully

Comment: From what I understand I can just add ` buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },` which inserts the button into dialog without having to create an external link. I see the button. I can even get an alert to trigger but it just wouldn't close : /

Comment: replacing `$(this)` with `dlg` in the button's function doesnt do the trick?

Comment: @mkoryak: yes! that got it to work. I would have thought `$(this)` refers to the same object.

Comment: probably refers to the button

Comment: sorry I didnt get back sooner.. the concept of `a.closeDialog` is based on the assumption that your placing a link, button, other as you do with `a.view` somewhere to invoke the close of the dialog