# Close dialog box from other function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a dialog box it shows some menus and when I click on any menu it shows another popup window. When I finished my work from popup, I want that the dialog box closes automatically.

Please suggest how can I do this.

**jQuery:**

```
function() { 
  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
  window.parent.pmsSession.scrollposition = true;
  window.parent.pmsSession.appointmenttime = fromTime;
  window.parent.$("#gridcontainer").reload();
  CloseModelWindow();
  $( '#options' ).dialog( "close" );        
}
```

Comment: Please, provide your code. What dialog are talking about? jQuery UI?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933826/how-to-close-jquery-dialog-within-the-dialog

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: do you want to close the dialog box when you click a button in the popup? - When do you call the function? - Would be great if you could provide us more code/details

Comment: what is this???????????

Answer (score 0):

When you finish your work-- write this

```
$("#idDialog").dialog("close");
```

it means you are manually closing the dialog

Answer (score 0):

When you are done, you just call:

```
$("#dialog_id").dialog('close');
```

Comment: I have corrected my answer as you're right. He doesn't say much about where and what he is doing.

Answer (score 0):

When you finish your work-- write this

```
$("#idDialog").dialog("close");
```