# How do I manually close a jquery-dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is my pop up:

[image]

I make a popup with javascript but I dont know how to close it, I already make a close button like this [x], but I want make another close button when user click "no" button, then popup is close.

This is my javascript code:

```
var popupDialogAll = function(title, url, w, h) {
    $.Dialog({
        width: "80%",
        height: "80%",
        padding: 10,
        shadow: true,
        title: title,
        draggable: true,
        btnClose: true,
        onShow: function(_dialog){
            var content = _dialog.children('.content');
            content.load(url);
        }
    });
};
```

This is my view:

```
<form id="form_email" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
  <button id="email" class="bg-orange fg-white" onclick="url(<?php $this->common->reminder($tiket);?>)">Yes</button>
  <button class="bg-orange fg-white">No!</button>
</center>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnDone').click(function(reminder){
        $(this).parents(".popupDialogAll").dialog('close')
    });
    </script>
```

I dont know what I must do in "No" button

I try add a javascript function in my no button, but it still not close

Comment: Depends. What library are you using for the dialog? You should include it in your post, and tag it if possible.

Comment: Provide current status as fiddle

Comment: can you give me a example? @Rob

Comment: @pahlevi Not sure what you mean by an example. What is `$.Dialog`? Looks like a library to me. What library are you using to create the dialog?

Comment: i believe u using jquery dialog? [jquerydialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog), check the official website for more info

Comment: I am using jquery dialog @Rob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close jQuery Dialog within the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933826/how-to-close-jquery-dialog-within-the-dialog)

Comment: ooh  I am sorry I don't know if I duplicate it @Rob

Comment: @pahlevi No need to apologize. Please check that linked question and see if it solves your problem. If it solves your problem, you can click the banner at the top of your question to mark it as a duplicate. If it doesn't fix your issue, however, please add more details to your question explaining why it doesn't solve your issue

Comment: @Rob I already try it but that doesn't fix my issue, my popup still not close

Comment: @pahlevi Can you edit your question to include your attempt to close it?

Comment: @pahlevi Did you try with the selector `.ui-dialog-content` instead of `.popupDialogAll`?

Comment: @Rob I do but it's still same, not closed

Comment: @pahlevi as was mentioned, this does not look like jQuery Dialog. Please include info from your `<head>`.

Comment: what I must include? the main view or popup? @Twisty

Comment: @pahlevi please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve