# ASP.NET MVC: Dialog does not work after closing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a div that is meant to pop out as dialog when a button is selected. it works fine. The issue is that when the user closes the dialog, the button will not pop out the div again until the webpage is reloaded.

the button:

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddItem","Home")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Item</a>
```

jQuery on the button:

```
 function PopupForm(url) {
            var FormDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url).done(function (response) {
                FormDiv.html(response);

                popup = FormDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'Fill in item details',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 500,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide(); 
                    }
                 }
                });

            });
        }
```

AddItem View:

```
    <div id="form-dialog">
         //input fields here
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="CloseBtn"class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CloseBtn').click(function () {
            $('#form-dialog').dialog('close');
        });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: Try using close() instead.

this.dialog('close');

Comment: @ThomsonMixab it does not work for me :(

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do - what does _the button does not prompt the pop out_ mean? Do you mean that after pressing save on the popup, some other prompt needs to popup? Do you mean like a "Are You Sure?" question? Anything that needs to happen immediately in the browser (without posting back to the server) needs to be built in javascript. Where is the "prompt the pop out" javascript code?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have edited my question

Comment: there is no other pop out, only the div

Comment: By "the button will not prompt the div again " do you mean "the button will not popup the div again"?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes nick

Comment: @ThomsonMixab is correct - use `this.dialog('close');` instead of `this.remove();`. Please don't say "it doesn't work" - please explain what happens. Does it not close the dialog or does it continue with the issue that you can't open it a second time? Does the console in F12 say anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close jQuery Dialog within the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933826/how-to-close-jquery-dialog-within-the-dialog)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid tried adding button to close the div within the dialog. But now the div cannot be closed now